# explode using two foreach loop not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display numbers separated by `,` from `mysql` table.

my code is,

```
$result = $check->result_array();

foreach($result as $res):
    $order_id = explode(",", $res["order_id"]); // $res["order_id"] = "1,2,"

    foreach($order_id as $ord_id):
        echo $ord_id; // output: 1
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_order o INNER JOIN tbl_contacts c ON c.contacts_id = o.contacts_id LEFT JOIN tbl_title t ON t.title_id = c.title_id LEFT JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.order_id = o.order_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.assign_id,max(u.status_id) as maxid FROM tbl_unit_status u group by u.assign_id) uu ON uu.assign_id = a.assign_id LEFT JOIN tbl_unit_status u2 on u2.status_id = uu.maxid LEFT JOIN tbl_cutter cu ON cu.cutter_id = u2.cutter_id LEFT JOIN tbl_worker w ON w.worker_id = u2.worker_id WHERE a.central_status = 1 AND a.central_assign_unit = 2 AND o.order_id != "'.$ord_id.'"  ORDER BY a.assign_id DESC');
        $count = $query->num_rows();

        if($count > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

for the above code the output is `1`. But i want the output as `12`. What is wrong in my coding. How to solve this problem. Thank you.

I have edited my code. Above is my actual code. while using sql query inside second foreach loop the output is `1`.

Comment: you want as 12 (twelve)?

Comment: It's very unusual to use the `foreach ... endforeach` notation and much more common to use `foreach { ... }` instead. Where'd you learn this style?

Comment: I tried...its working fine...

Comment: check your input, no problem with code. Check [Demo](https://eval.in/741518)

Comment: How many rows are getting returned in $result ?

Comment: @Naincy : 1 row

Comment: First of all I do not see any issue in your code...and its working fine for me. But if you just want to remove `,` from that then you can use str_replace that also will work. Then you will not need explode and foreach. Something like this echo str_replace(',','', $res["order_id"]);

Comment: print_r($order_id); after explode and share

Comment: @Naincy : `print_r($order_id) : Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => )` and `print_r($ord_id) : 1`

Comment: @JithinVarghese what is the `return 0;` hoping to achieve? Your loop always quits after only one iteration.

Comment: Also as a side note but it's generally a bad idea to run queries inside loops (performance wise) - at the least, they're better off as a stored procedure. Alternatively, use the SQL `IN(..)` syntax (or `NOT IN(..)` in this case).

Comment: @LukeBriggs : if the result from mysql table returns empty row then `return 0`

Comment: @JithinVarghese The two `return` statements mean your loop only ever runs once. I.e. paraphrasing, `if(more than one result){ quit } else { quit }`

Comment: As you're using return, I'd imagine this is in a function - what do you want it to actually return? Results from _all_ the orders combined together, or just the first one?

Comment: @LukeBriggs : all the orders

Comment: it will stop, if you return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Merge orders together

At the moment, you're using `return` inside your for loop. That means it will immediately quit when it hits that line, and doesn't loop any more. So instead, you add your returned values into an array, then *return that*:

```
$result = $check->result_array();

// This will be the returned value:
$orders = array();

foreach($result as $res) {
    $order_id = explode(",", $res["order_id"]); // $res["order_id"] = "1,2,"

    foreach($order_id as $ord_id) {

        // If your order_id string can end in ',' then watch out for empty ID's:
        if ($ord_id == '') {
            continue;
        }

        echo $ord_id; // output: 1
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_order o INNER JOIN tbl_contacts c ON c.contacts_id = o.contacts_id LEFT JOIN tbl_title t ON t.title_id = c.title_id LEFT JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.order_id = o.order_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.assign_id,max(u.status_id) as maxid FROM tbl_unit_status u group by u.assign_id) uu ON uu.assign_id = a.assign_id LEFT JOIN tbl_unit_status u2 on u2.status_id = uu.maxid LEFT JOIN tbl_cutter cu ON cu.cutter_id = u2.cutter_id LEFT JOIN tbl_worker w ON w.worker_id = u2.worker_id WHERE a.central_status = 1 AND a.central_assign_unit = 2 AND o.order_id != "'.$ord_id.'"  ORDER BY a.assign_id DESC');
        $count = $query->num_rows();

        if ($count > 0) {
            // We've got some results - merge into orders array:
            $orders = array_merge($orders, $query->result_array());
        }

    } // Removed endforeach; syntax (it's not very common)
}

// We can now return that orders set:
return $orders;
```

Note that I have not made any changes to the query itself; in general, for performance reasons, the above is much better off as either [a stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) or use the [`in(...)` syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) instead. That way, you only run one query and there's much less back-and-forth between PHP and your database server.